# What is wrong with this MySQL Trigger that prevents null dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create this trigger to prevent insertion of null dates:

```
CREATE TRIGGER responses_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON responses
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.date_of_plan IS NULL OR NEW.date_of_plan = '0000-00-00') THEN
SET NEW.date_of_plan = CURDATE();
END IF;
IF (NEW.date_of_update IS NULL OR NEW.date_of_update = '0000-00-00') THEN
SET NEW.date_of_update = CURDATE();
END IF;
END
```

However, I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it with a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing the delimiter before the query, ie. I executed

```
DELIMITER $$
```

Before the trigger query.

Comment: Haha i didnt realise you were the originator of the post ;/ ... changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like you did, you need a delimiter.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER responses_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON responses
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.date_of_plan IS NULL OR NEW.date_of_plan = '0000-00-00') THEN
SET NEW.date_of_plan = CURDATE();
END IF;
IF (NEW.date_of_update IS NULL OR NEW.date_of_update = '0000-00-00') THEN
SET NEW.date_of_update = CURDATE();
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can also set it back as done on the last line. Better practie!